# Python PyQt5 весь текст в QTextBrowser становится 'гиперактивным'

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, url

У меня проблема с текстом в QTextBrowser. У меня есть такой код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.textBox = QTextBrowser(centralWidget)

        self.textBox.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.button = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.button.setText("PUSH")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.pressed)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textBox)

    def pressed(self):
        id = 49309034
        url_name = "test_link"
        link = '<a href = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{0}> {1} </a>'.format(id, url_name)
        dict = {'Key': 'Value', link: 'Test link'}
        for key, value in dict.items():
            self.textBox.append('{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
        self.textBox.append("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, я получаю следующее:
[Main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6fB6.png)

Однако, если я перехожу по ссылке, а затем снова нажимаю на кнопку - весь текст в QTextBrowser становится 'гиперактивным':  ['Hyperactive' text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYS9A.png)

Я думаю, что проблема в 'переходе на новую строку'. Потому что я попробовал написать так, и у меня все выводится нормально:

```
string = ""
for key, value in dict.items():
    string += '{0}: {1}'.format(key, value) + '; '
self.textBox.append(string)
```

[Main Window(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc2iY.png)

[После того, как я перешел по ссылке и нажал снова на кнопку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNJki.png)

Можете помочь разобраться с этим?

Comment: как будто </a> не закрылась. предроложу что стирает символ. добавь пробел в конце

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте добавляемые строки оборачивать в тег (можно и в `<div>`), например:

```
self.textBox.append('<span>{0}: {1}</span>'.format(key, value))
```

---

Пример:

```
def pressed(self):
    id = 49309034
    url_name = "test_link"
    link = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{0}">{1}</a>'.format(id, url_name)
    dict = {'Key': 'Value', link: 'Test link'}
    for key, value in dict.items():
        self.textBox.append('<span>{0}: {1}</span>'.format(key, value))
    self.textBox.append("")
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переместить курсор перед добавление строк в QTextBrowser.
Например так:

```
self.textBox.moveCursor(self.textBox.textCursor().Start)
```

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.textBox = QTextBrowser(centralWidget)

        self.textBox.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.button = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.button.setText("PUSH")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.pressed)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textBox)

    def pressed(self):

        self.textBox.moveCursor(self.textBox.textCursor().Start)       # <---

        id = 49309034
        url_name = "test_link"
        link = '<a href = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{0}> {1} </a>'.format(id, url_name)
        dict = {'Key': 'Value', link: 'Test link'}
        for key, value in dict.items():
            self.textBox.append('{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
        self.textBox.append("")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]